# Converting string to timestamp in PySpark or SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am struggling converting a string to timestamp in SparkSQL.

Here is my code:

```
to_timestamp(date_time_column, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS')
```

It returns null. Something must be wrong with the parameter 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'

Sample string data from date_time_column: 05/30/2023 20:28:41.6487480Z

Can someone help correct the above code?

Big Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSX` format in `to_timestamp`.

**`Example:`**

```
spark.sql("""select  to_timestamp('05/30/2023 20:28:41.6487480Z','MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSX') as ts""").show(10,False)
#+--------------------------+
#|ts                        |
#+--------------------------+
#|2023-05-30 20:28:41.648748|
#+--------------------------+
```